# CSS Table Borders- Horizontal only with unique table & heading borders

Tags: html, css

I am trying to style a simple table:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Title1</th>
    <th>Title2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cell</td>
    <td>Cell</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cell</td>
    <td>Cell</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I want the table to have horizontal borders at the top and bottom, and the heading to have a horizontal border at the bottom:

[image: Little Styled Table]

This seems to work fine when I do not have a containing div identified by ID:

[JS Fiddle 1 (working)](http://jsfiddle.net/XPyzM/242/)

Once I put it in a containing div it is failing:

[JS Fiddle 2 (not working)](http://jsfiddle.net/XPyzM/245/)

Using CSS I can achieve this using firebug.  Somehow trying to put it in the style sheet is causing it to fail (the th borders are not showing up).  Any ideas?

**EDIT**
A typo I had was found, but as my original was not working, I have updated the above to show the error I am running into.  The problem is somehow with adding a containing div and identifying the table by its ID.

Comment: It works just fine http://jsfiddle.net/XPyzM/244/ (btw you missed a bracket in your jsfiddle whick was causing this issue)

Comment: The CSS in your fiddle has an extra `}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/XPyzM/243/

```
table {
    border-top: 2px solid black;
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}
```

was containing a bracket extra

UPdated for the new issue:
http://jsfiddle.net/XPyzM/247/

Check it out if you have any problems..

Comment: I see your fix and I see it is working in the JSFiddle.  For some reason it is still not working on my actual page.  I am seeing if I can update my question or if I need to create a new one.  Thanks for the help.  I am going to wait a minute to select this answer so I can see what is going on.

Comment: that's strange.. so you are not getting the border-bottom of th or nothing's working..

Comment: actually you were using #mytable th in place of #mytable table th